# Display errors message from Laravel8 response

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to import data from excel file to database using laravel and maatwebsite excel package

So I'm using the following code :

```
class ProjectsImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow,WithValidation

{
     use Importable;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */

     public function rules(): array
    {

    return [
       
         'nom' => 'required',
         'prenom' => 'required',
         'cine' => 'required|unique:castings',
    ];

    }
    public function customValidationMessages()
    {

    return [
         
         'nom.required' => 'Le nom est requis',
         'prenom.required' => 'Le prénom est requis',
         'cine.required' => 'Le CINE est requis',
         'cine.unique' => 'Le CINE a déjà été pris',
       ];
  }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
            $casting = new Casting();
            
            $representant = new Representant();

                $casting->nom = $row['nom'];
                $casting->prenom= $row['prenom'];
                $casting->cine = $row['cine'];
                $casting->save();
        }
}
```

My Controller :

```
public function importFile(){
          
         Excel::import(new ProjectsImport,request()->file('fichier'));
          return response()->json(['success' => 'Data is successfully added']);
    }
```

My script :

```
 $('#fileform').on('submit', function(event){
          event.preventDefault();

           $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('castingss.importFile') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataSrc: "",
            contentType: false,
            cache:false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
             var html = '';
             if(data.errors)
             {
              html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
              for(var count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++)
              {
               html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
              }
              html += '</div>';
             }
             if(data.success)
             {
              
              html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
             
             
             table.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
             }
             $('#form_result2').html(html);
            }
           })
         
        });
```

When all works fine I get in my view the message of success (Data is successfully added) , But when for example I have an error the error is displayed on the network and not on my view

I get only the succes message in my view bit in the case of errors I get the messages on network

How can I display the errors message in my view in this case ?

**UPDATE**

With this code I get in my network :

```
message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: [["There was an error on row 2. Le CINE a déjà été pris"]]
0: ["There was an error on row 2. Le CINE a déjà été pris"]
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

How can I display that in my view ?

Comment: I think you'll need an `error` function in your ajax https://stackoverflow.com/a/2833968/7498116

Comment: how can I do that , an example if you can

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ please chack my update

Comment: Should I add  `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(XMLHttpRequest); console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown); }` , in my script after `dataType:"json",` ?

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: I `get Unprocessable Entity
castingss:1372 error
castingss:1372 Unprocessable Entity`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display Laravel validation errors with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340608/display-laravel-validation-errors-with-ajax)